# Are these frequencies permitted in Colombia?

Tags: radio, frequencies

I am from Norway and going to Colombia to shoot a short documentary. I am a videographer, not an experienced sound person, therefore I need a bit of help.

I have some Sennheiser receiver/transmitter kits with the frequencies of 566 - 608 MHz. Which frequencies are used for wireless microphones in Colombia? Can I use these kits?

Answer (score 1):

On [Sennheiser's](https://sennheiseruk.happyfox.com/kb/article/199-using-frequencies-in-different-countries) website they supposedly offer a “Frequency Advisor” I couldn't find it, but you can also use the [Sennheiser Worldwide](https://en-uk.sennheiser.com/about-sennheiser-at-a-glance-sennheiser-worldwide) webpage to get contact info for their sales partners and tech support for whichever country. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A key word to search for is the term "[PMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programme_making_and_special_events)" together with the country name.

The guide for RF frequency allocations from Sennheiser is at 
https://en-us.sennheiser.com/sifa

It does not seem to have information about Colombia.